# Setting up RNN in TensorFlow for time series forecast with variable input series lengths

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, time-series, lstm, rnn

I am building a model with `keras` for time series prediction. The structure of the problem is as follows:

- The input is a time series of 5 numeric features
- The output is a binary class (0 or 1)
- The model needs to predict on variable lengths of input data. For example, in some cases I might only have the first 2 days available for a sample, and in others I may have 7 days.

Here is how I am setting up the layers in the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(None, 5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I am seeing good performance when training on sequences of a constant size and predicting on that same size. However, I am not sure how to best configure and train the model to work on variable-length inputs.

I'm wondering if there might be zero-padding going on under the hood when the sequences aren't all the same length. Values of 0 are common and meaningful for the features I am using and so filling in missing data with 0's wouldn't make sense to do in this case.

I'm also wondering how people usually structure their training set in this case. I could do any of the following:

- Include each sample only once with a random input length
- Include each sample once *per* possible input length, with a different input length each time
- Include each sample only once, with the maximum input length

The third doesn't seem right as the model probably needs to see training examples with shorter lengths in order to be able to predict on them.

Comment: Would you be able to show a graph of your time series? From my experience, LSTMs do better at forecasting volatile data but not data with a strong trend - I can better assess if this is the case by looking at your series.

Comment: @MichaelGrogan it's not a single time series - rather a collection of several samples for which I wish to produce predictions based on a small number of time steps (between 1 and 7-14). The individual samples are definitely too volatile to fit traditional timeseries models to, which is why I'm looking to leverage LSTM.

Comment: This is a type of question where it's unfortunately not possible for me to offer meaningful advice without seeing the data up close.